# Redirect a user to a specific state after a certain amount of time

Tags: angularjs, session, events, angular-ui-router, timeout

I have a service that gives me the amount of milliseconds that the user can be logged in, `SecurityServices.getUserLoginDuration()`, this time duration is shown on top of all pages, so I have written a directive that displays this time.

```
<session-timeout value="60000"></session-timeout>
```

or

```
 <session-timeout value="$root.timeoutValue"></session-timeout>
```

I use this piece of code to redirect user to login page after specific amount of time has passed:

```
$scope.timeout = $scope.timeoutValue;

    $interval(decrementBySecond, 1000);

    $timeout(emitSessionTimeout, $scope.timeoutValue);

    function decrementBySecond() {
        $scope.timeout = $scope.timeout - 1000;           
    }

    function emitSessionTimeout() {
        $rootScope.$emit('SESSION_TIMEOUT');
    }
```

and in `run` block of my application I handle the `SESSION_TIMEOUT` event like this:

```
 app.run(handleTimeOut);

 function handleTimeout($rootScope, $state) {
        $rootScope.$on('SESSION_TIMEOUT', function () {
            $state.go('login');
        });
    }
```

timeout value should be refreshed on each state change so `$scope.timeout` in directive controller should be initialized to its initial value. how can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't think such things should be done in the frontend. Set expiration date for your sessions in the backend, and return `401 UNAUTHORIZED` status if API is called with expired session.

Comment: @JahongirRahmonov server side logic is not still developed, so I need some way to simulate or mimic this behavior, what you say can easily be done with the help of interceptors and I am aware of this ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some modification to my directive and with the help of two-way data binding, I got my desired result:

here is the modification:

```
$scope.timeout = angular.copy($scope.timeoutValue);

$interval(decrementBySecond, 1000);

$timeout(emitSessionTimeout, $scope.timeout);

function decrementBySecond() {
    $scope.timeoutValue= $scope.timeoutValue- 1000;           
}

function emitSessionTimeout() {
    $rootScope.$emit('SESSION_TIMEOUT');
}
```

I receive `timeoutValue` from two-way data binding from directive isolated scope and the scope that the directive is used, `$rootScope.timeoutValue` is changed by each state transition so every state change this value is updated and its new value is reflected in directive, and changes in directive are also reflected in view.